# How would i get live updates when a user joins and leaves a discord voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is there a way too do a callback or a background task to see when a user joins and leaves a voicechannel? Currently when I cmd the bot I only am able to see the users that are currently in the voicechannel only. Sorry if it might not make sense.

````
import asyncio
import config

client = discord.Client() 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

    #Voice channel 
    lobby_voicechannel = client.get_channel(708339994871463986)

    #Text channel
    txt_channel = client.get_channel(702908501533655203)

    team_one = []
    team_two = []   
    member_id = []

    lobby_queue = lobby_voicechannel.members

    for x in lobby_queue:

        #change mention to name or nick for variations
        member_id.append(x.mention) 

    player_num = len(member_id)
    joined_user = str(member_id)

    #check how many players in total for queue
    if player_num == 5:

        user_convert = tuple(member_id)

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="**{}/10** players joined `{}`".format(player_num, lobby_voicechannel),
            description="\n".join(user_convert),
            color=0x00f2ff)

        await txt_channel.send(delete_after=None, embed=embed)
    else:
        if player_num == 0:

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**{}/10** players joined `{}`".format(player_num, lobby_voicechannel),
                description=f"***```No players in {lobby_voicechannel}```***",
                color=0x00f2ff
            )
            await txt_channel.send(delete_after=None, embed=embed)


client.run(config.Token)```
````

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.on_voice_state_update) event. This event gets triggered whenever a member joins/leaves or when a members state changes in a voice channel. For more info see link.

However you still need to check whether or not the member left/joined. This can be done through the `before` and `after` VoiceState objects received from the event: `on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):`.

Example:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel == None and after.channel != None:
        state = 'joined'
    else if before.channel != None and after.channel == None:
        state = 'left'
    else:
        state = 'unchanged'

    # Continue with some code
```

Comment: Thanks mate ill give it a go and let you know

Comment: Make sure to mark this answer as "right answer" if it helped you